# Loading A Byte Array taking too long?

Tags: java, android

I hired someone to code my app. It loads a instrumental downloaded from the internet to my app.  To download the instrumental it is fast but when loading the instrumental it takes a really long time at least a minute or more.  I looked over the code to see where it would be slowing it down but i can't seem to figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Code:
        //File loading task

```
 class SaveInputStreamTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

            private Context context;
            ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

            public SaveInputStreamTask(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();

                // mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                 //mProgressDialog.setMessage("Beat Will Take A Minute To Load When Mixing So Start Recording");
                mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "Beat Will Take Up To A Minute To Load. In The Meantime How's Your Day?");
                 mProgressDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {

                try
                {
                    File file = new File(instrument_file_name);
                    long totalFilesize = file.length();
                    long readSize = 0;
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    saveInputStream(fis);
                    return "SUCCESS";
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
                // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
                mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                if(result == null){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Loading Beat failed. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RecordRap.this.finish();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }

            public void saveInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException
            {
                int n = 0;
                DataInputStream in1;
                in1 = new DataInputStream(is);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                try 
                {

                    while ((n = in1.read()) != -1) 
                    {
                        bos.write(n);
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e)
                {   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bos.toByteArray());
                bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                ShortBuffer sb = bb.asShortBuffer();

                for (int i = 0; i < sb.capacity(); i++) {
                    beatsShortList.add(sb.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Because you're reading one byte at a time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stackoverflow isn't a freelance code-review service.

Comment: @323go how is this a code review.  I tried to solve this myself and i couldnt figure it out so i asked on stack overflow.  Im not asking anyone to write my code, i am just trying to figure out the problem is so i can find a solution.

Comment: @323go - Mind you, the freelancer who wrote that did a pretty poor job.  Indeed, there are signs that he >>might<< have done it deliberately.  (Notice how he has extracted the file size into a variable ... and not used it.  He could have been intending to allocate a `byte[]` and then read the file into the `byte[]` in one operation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to @Stephen C the problem was `while ((n = in1.read()) != -1)` so i added a buffer and changed the code to the following and the problem is fixed now loading only takes a few seconds. Thanks to Stephen C for the help and as Ratul Sharker.

Updated code:

```
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[0xFFFF];

                    while ((n = in1.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        bos.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    }
```

Comment: Since this is the answer to your question, you should [mark it accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < sb.capacity(); i++) {
    beatsShortList.add(sb.get(i));
}
```

This is the culprit what are you looking for :)

Comment: I doubt it.  The problem is probably here: `while ((n = in1.read()) != -1)`

Comment: thank you guys for your help the issue was in the while statement.